# finding a free port with nodeJS and portscannerJS

Tags: node.js, port

I'm trying to create a small app that scans some pages using phantomJS, I want this done in a for loop , so I attempted to do so based on this question:

This question is similiar - [How can i ensure this loop runs as expected in node.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20355956/how-can-i-ensure-this-loop-runs-as-expected-in-node-js)

Only my code produces this -

```
{ [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect' }
```

over and over again (the times of my for loop).
Here is my code:

```
    var startPort = 3000;
    var endPort = 5000;
    var toSend = [];
    for (var dataIndex = 0; dataIndex < 5; dataIndex++) {
        portscanner.findAPortNotInUse(startPort, endPort, '127.0.0.1', function(err, freeport) {
            if (err) {
                return console.log(err + " " + freeport);
            }
            console.log(freeport);

            startPort = freeport + 1;// correct the start port to search from

            phantom.create({'port': freeport},function(ph) {
                ph.createPage(function(page) {
                    var requestNumber = data[3];
                    page.open("http://something...", function(status) {
....
```

So in this code I just get that error 5 times (# of loop iterations)
I'm running the code on localhost on port 3000. 
Any ideas why it can't find any ports?